# Git - Update all new commits from master branch to an existed tag

Tags: git, github

Can I update all new commits from `master` branch to an existed tag?

This is how I created the tag:

```
git tag -a v2.0 -m "Version 2.0"
git push origin v2.0
```

After that, I pushed some minor changes on `master` branch.

```
git add .
git commit -m "Minor changes"
git push origin master
```

Now the tag has "1 commit to master since this tag". I want to push that commit to `v2.0` tag too.

I tried to `git checkout v2.0`, then `git pull origin master` to commit the change to the tag. But after pull from master, the git shows something like `8c62508` instead of `v2.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike branches, when you check out a tag you'll end up on a detached head. You simply can't pull into a tag. It *is* possible to update a tag (I believe you need to delete and recreate it), but it's a really bad idea since Git won't update an existing tag when it changes upstream unless specifically asked to do so. You'd therefore risk having multiple opinions of what a tag points to. You're better off treating tags as immutable. Version numbers are cheap.